# Zsh: dirs in reverse order

Tags: shell, zsh, cd-command

I am a bit confused about how `dirs` works. The documentation says:

> dirs
>
> With no arguments, print the contents of the directory stack.
>   Directories are added to this stack with the `pushd` command, and
>   removed with the `cd` or `popd` commands.

**Q1.** I never use `popd` nor `pushd`, but I noticed that `dirs`keeps track of the directories where I have been (which to me means, that `cd` ***adds***, not removes, directories to the stack)

**Q.2** After a long session using `cd`, it's common for `dirs` to print a long list of directories, but this list prints the most recent directory first and it ends with the last directory, so if I have a long list, the screen scrolls, and I can't easily see the most recent set of directories (which are typically the ones I am most interested in).

How can I print the list of directories in reverse order?

I tried `dirs | sort -r`, but this does not sort the entries correctly, e.g. I get

```
20 /foo20/bar
2  /foo2/bar
19 ...
18
...
16
11
10
1
0
```

The unsorted originals look like

```
1 /foo/bar
2 /foo2/bar
3  ...
..  
9
10
11
..
20
21
..
30
```

Comment: You would be better served showing some actual unsorted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A1**

Did you enable `AUTO_PUSHD`?

It can be enabled with `setopt autopushd` or `set -N`.

That will be why `cd` is adding to the directory stack.

**A2**

I assume you're running `dirs -v`, not just `dirs`?  (I think `-v` is required to make it list one per line.)

Why not just `dirs -v | head`?  Or `dirs -v | less`?  (Or `dirs | tac` as qqx suggests.)

Answer (score 5):

`sort` by default does sorting based on ASCII values, this will not correctly sort numbers with varying numbers of digits. You can use the `-n` option to tell it to sort based on a leading numeric value.

```
dirs -v | sort -nr
```

Or, since the output of `dirs` comes already sorted but you just want to get that into reverse order you can use the `tac` command (that's `cat` in reverse):

```
dirs -p | tac
```

Answer (score 3):

I do `cd +` and then hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> so see and navigate the list of recently visited directories, with the latest one at the top.

Answer (score 2):

if you simply `sort -r` you are arranging the lines in descending order collating from the first character onward to the end of each line.  You need to confine the sort key to the second field if you want an "alphabetic" sort:

```
dirs | sort -rk2,2
```

This specifies a (r)everse order sort with the sort (k)ey being field two (2) though field (2).  By default, fields are whitespace delimited.  If they aren't you can specify the separator with `-t`.

If on the other hand you truly want to order numerically, do:

```
dirs | sort -rkn1,1
```